# SQL Server, convert an alphanumeric string to upper case alphanumeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need code to convert '1a234grh7eg79ef'  to '1A234GRH7EG79EF' in sql server.

Comment: These are very basics in sql server google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UPPER` function

```
Select UPPER(yourcolumn)
From yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @String varchar(max)='1a234grh7eg79ef'

SELECT UPPER(@String)
```